# Trying to make it so that I can use a div to open a div, close any other open divs, and scroll to the div I clicked to open it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Sorry if that was confusing. I have a set of six divs with titles in them. I'd like it so that when you click on the div, a new div opens up under the title displaying information. When a user clicks the next title, I want it to close the open div, open the new div, and scroll to the title of the newly open div.

So far, I can get it to do everything except scroll to the div that I just clicked. I've tried a lot of different codes that I've found on here, but I don't know jquery well enough to figure it out. Any help would be most appreciated.

You can see the page here - http://justinj16.sg-host.com/services/

Only the first two tabs are set up to open right now (didn't want to put any more time into it if I couldn't get this to work).

Here is the code that I was using -

```
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  //Hide all content to be revealed
  $('.reveal_content').hide();

  //Create the click event for each reveal button
  $('.reveal_button').click(function (e) {

  //Prevent the default button action (i.e. redirecting to a url)
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the parent section for the button clicked
  $parent_section = $(this).closest('.reveal_section');

  //Remove the opened class from all other buttons
  $('.reveal_button').not(this).removeClass('opened');

  //Close all content in other sections
  $('.reveal_section').not($parent_section).find('.reveal_content').fadeOut('slow');

  //Hide/Reveal the content in the same section as the button clicked
  $(this).addClass('opened');
  $parent_section.find('.reveal_content').each(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle();
  }
  )

  });

  }
)</script>
```

Comment: Do you strictly want a jquery solution or can make do with a vanilla JS solution?

Comment: could you just set an example here on a snippet with only that part that bothers you. Not many will be happy to dig into your all codes to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS solution, maybe someone else can help you with a JQuery solution.
Take the div element into a variable, let's say `el`. And then do:
`el.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});`

Your div in question, will be scrolled into view.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/s0z4xpg5/)

You can play with some options to scroll it to center or end; refer here: [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do have a question as I've never used vanilla JS before. How do I take the div element into a variable, and how would I incorporate this into my jquery. Sorry, I realize that this is a dumb question, but I'm a novice when it comes to coding.

Comment: Jquery is actually based on Vanilla JS. Usually now, people suggest using Vanilla JS more, because browsers can directly use it, whereas Jquery needs the CDN or some sort of script file included, so it adds extra bloat. For your actual question: https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/s0z4xpg5/ (It's a very basic fiddle with similar layout to yours). Click on the bottom blue div and you'll see the scroll action!
Though yes, it might seem a little complex, given you said you're new to coding. It's elegant, and fast, but can be hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
$("h2").click(function() {
  $(".content.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().find(".content").addClass("active");

  $("html,body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".content.active").offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.block {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  height: auto;
  padding: 40px 0px;
}

.content {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content.active {
  max-height: unset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <div class="content">
      this is a content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <div class="content">
      this is a content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <div class="content">
      this is a content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <div class="content">
      this is a content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <div class="content">
      this is a content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h2>title</h2>
    <div class="content">
      this is a content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```